# Which of this is the best way to implement an app with bottom navigation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to create an app with the BottomNavigationView provided by Android Support Library. But should I use just one activity that contains the BottomBar and also Fragments that will be the main content of each section ? Or is best to use multiple activities ? each of which will have a BottomNavigationView

I personally prefer the latter, but looking for implementations on the internet I saw that people tend to duplicate the logic for the BottomBar on each Activity. 
Also, I couldn't find the answer in Android documentation, but maybe thay say something about this that I didn't see.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically just down to design choice.  I prefer the former: one activity with fragments and one BottomBar.  It's a little bit easier to keep everything smooth when you have a single bar then when you have to constantly be loading a new one for each screen in your app.

When I do things like this, I would use one activity with a bottom bar, and swap out the information on the screen with fragments, keeping the same bottom bar for all screens.  You could swap out elements of it between screens if you needed to.

Comment: I see your point, I'm new to Android so I don't have too much experience, but I've read that this solution may cause problems when you need Fragments inside the different sections of your app, since you'll have nested Fragments. Did you experience something like this ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little?  When would you have nested Fragments?  To be clear, you will have some other activities, i.e. maybe a Settings activity, etc, but those would be used for totally different sections of the app.  I meant that the main section of your app would be one activity with many fragments.

Comment: Suppouse that in your BottomBar you have Feed, Search and Profile sections. From what I understand you will have just one activity containing the BottomBar, that will show three Fragments, one for each section. Now, in case you need another Fragment in your Feed section, you´ll end up with a "main" Fragment for you Feed section, that will also have another Fragment nested, am I right ?

Comment: Yeah that all sounds right, but you should be able to just swap out the fragment inside the feed, it doesn't need to be inside of the first fragment